# React Native | Get Switch Value from another Component

Tags: react-native

I would like to get the value of the switch inside **ToggleCampus** from **Map.js**. How can I update the value of the state inside Map.js from ToggleCampus.js?

Map.js

```
export default class Map extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { switchVal: true};
    }

    render(){
        return (
             <ToggleCampus switchVal = {this.state.switchVal} />   
        );
    }
}
```

ToggleCampus.js

```
export default class ToggleCampus extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.props.switchVal);
        return(
                <Switch
                    value={this.props.switchVal}
                    *(not sure how to use onChange here)*
                />
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So basically what you have to do is pass the function as props to ToggleCampus to update the switchVal. Like suppose in ToggleCampus you want to change the value on button click, so check the below method:

Map.js

```
    export default class Map extends React.Component{
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = { switchVal: true};
        }
       changeSwitch = (value) => {
this.setState({switchVal:value});
}

        render(){
            return (
                 <ToggleCampus changeSwitch={this.changeSwitch} switchVal = {this.state.switchVal} />   // passed changeSwitch
            );
        }
    }
```

and in togglecampus.js

```
export default class ToggleCampus extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.props.switchVal);
        return(
<>
                <Switch
                    value={this.props.switchVal}
                    *(not sure how to use onChange here)*
                />
<Button title="click" onPress={() => this.props.changeSwitch(false)} /> // added this
           </>     
        );
    }
}
```

hope it helps.